# List structure comparison

Tags: python, list

Task is to write a function ***same-structure_as*** which returns
***True*** or ***False*** when it takes to lists compares there nesting structure.

For Example:

```
should return True same_structure_as([ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ] ) same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ 2, [ 2, 2 ] ] )

should return False  same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ], 2 ] ) same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2 ], 2 ] )
```

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def same_structure_as(original, other):
    count = 0
    if len(original) == len(other):
        for i in range(0, len(original) - 1):
            if isinstance(original[i], int) == isinstance(other[i],
                    int):
                count += 1
            elif len(original[i]) == len(other[i]):
                count += 1
    else:
        return False

    if count == len(original) - 1:
        return True
```

This code goes over every element of both lists and check if they are integers or sub-list(having same elements). When I run it i get this error:

```
elif len(original[i])==len(other[i]):TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

A rule that I try to always follow when design programs in Python is to ***never trust the user***. This implies always checking for the type of the inputs you got, making sure the parameters you got have a valid value...

In your first `if`, you tested if both items are int, but you cannot assume after that both aren't. What if one is an int and the other a list (which is exactly the case here) ?

You should add more type checking, like this :

```py
def same_structure_as(original, other):
    count = 0
    if len(original) == len(other):
        for i in range(0, len(original) - 1):
            if isinstance(original[i], int) == isinstance(other[i],
                    int):
                count += 1
            elif (isinstance(original[i], list) and
                  isinstance(other[i], list) and
                  len(original[i]) == len(other[i])):
                count += 1
    else:
        return False

    if count == len(original) - 1:
        return True
```

That being said, it's possible (and perhaps better) to avoid having to run the whole loop and to stop the first time you encounter a difference:

```py
def same_structure_as(original, other):

    # This avoids to make useless computations when they are not necessary
    if not isinstance(original, list) or not isinstance(other, list)
        # You can even raise a TypeError, to inform the user
        # that they should make sure to provid two lists
        return False

    if len(original) != len(other):
        return False

    for index in range(len(original)):
        if isinstance(original[index], list) and isinstance(other[index], list):
            if type(original[index]) != type(other[index]):
                # This would happen for example with [1, ...] and [[1], ...]
                return False
            if len(original[index]) != len(other[index]):
                # This would happen for example with [[1, 1], ...] and [[1], ...]
                return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a recursive solution.

Also, the solution can easily weed out situations where it should return `False`, so those should be tested for first, eg. different type elements and lists of different lengths.

Also its easy to say that two items which are both `int`s will be considered the same.

```
def same_structure_as(original, other):
    if type(original) != type(other):
        return False
    if isinstance(original, int):
        return True
    if len(original) != len(other):
        return False
    for orig_elem, other_elem in zip(original, other):
        if not same_structure_as(orig_elem, other_elem):
            return False
    return True
```

Also note that the above function produces these results:

```
same_structure_as(1, 2): True
same_structure_as([], []): True
same_structure_as([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]): True
same_structure_as([1, [1, 1]], [2, [2, 2]]): True

same_structure_as(1, []): False
same_structure_as([1], []): False
same_structure_as([[1]], [[]]): False
same_structure_as([1, [1, 1]], [[2, 2], 2]): False
same_structure_as([1, [1, 1]], [[2], 2]): False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_depths(d, c = 0):
  if not isinstance(d, list):
     yield c
  else:
     for i in d:
       yield from get_depths(i, c+1)
```

---

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def same_structure_as(a, b):
   return all(c == d for c, d in zip_longest(get_depths(a), get_depths(b)))

same_structure_as([ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ] ) 
same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ 2, [ 2, 2 ] ] )
same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ], 2 ] ) 
same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2 ], 2 ] )
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another statement for `elif` - check if both elements are `list`

Try this:

```
elif isinstance(original[i], list) and isinstance(other[i], list) and len(original[i]) == len(other[i]):
```

Also, your function should return False if last `if` statement is not `True` - you can add another `else` in the end or add `return False` without another `else`

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that original [i] or other [i] can be an int and not a list because the previous if returns true only if BOTH elements are int.
One solution could be :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def same_structure_as(original, other):
    count = 0
    if len(original) == len(other):
        for i in range(len(original)):
            if isinstance(original[i], int) == isinstance(other[i], int):
                count += 1
            elif isinstance(original[i], int) and not isinstance(other[i], int):
                return False
            elif not isinstance(original[i], int) and isinstance(other[i], int):
                return False
            elif same_structure_as(original[i], other[i]):
                count += 1
    else:
        return False
    if count == len(original):
        return True

if same_structure_as([ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ] ):
    print("True expected True")
else:
    print("False expected True")
if same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ 2, [ 2, 2 ] ] ):
    print("True expected True")
else:
    print("False expected True")


if same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2, 2 ], 2 ] ):
    print("True expected False")
else:
    print("False expected False")
if same_structure_as([ 1, [ 1, 1 ] ], [ [ 2 ], 2 ] ):
    print("True expected False")
else:
    print("False expected False")
```

Output :

```
True expected True
True expected True
False expected False
False expected False
```